# find sentence occurrence in string

Tags: java, regex

I have file content in string form. I need to get the count of partcular sentence say  `"My name is scott"` in string that can span across lines like

```
some content ... "My name is scott"  some content ...

some content ... "My name is " +  
    "scott"  some content ...
```

It would be great if i can get  two versions i.e. to Firs one to find the given input when in single line . Second one can search across lines also ?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: You only have to do this `My\\s+name\\s+is\\s+scott`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll` to replace that break part :

```
" +  
    "
```

like this :

```
String text = "some content ... \"My name is scott\"  some content ...\n"
        + "\n"
        + "some content ... \"My name is \" +  \n"
        + "    \"scott\"  some content ...";
String textToMatche = "My name is scott";
text = text.replaceAll("\"\\s*\\+\\s*\n\\s*\"", "");// Note the regex : \"\s*\+\s*\n\s*\"
```

**result :**

```
some content ... "My name is scott"  some content ...

some content ... "My name is scott"  some content ...
```

Then count the number of occurrence :

### Java 9+ version

```
long count = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(textToMatche)).matcher(text).results().count();
```

### Before Java 9

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(textToMatche));
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
int count = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    count += 1;
}
```

Output

```
2
```

### [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FXLF0R/1)

Comment: why do i need `pattern.quote` simply `Pattern.compile(textToMatche);` will work also ?

Comment: @scottmiles consider your input have a dot or brackets, this characters is a part of the regex syntax, so I use Pattern.compile to escape this characters that's all